# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:

Tags: java, sockets

I'm studying java and i recently got into the soquee issue. In the matter has this project to develop in which we simulate the part of the client and the server. The server part is apparently working perfectly, but every time I run the client part and try to put some text to be sent to the server pops up the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.faculdade.chat.Cliente.keyTyped(Ljava/awt/event/KeyEvent;)V
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6494)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6316)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1103)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:974)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:800)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Code follows below:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.faculdade.chat;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Marcos Henrique
 */
public class Cliente extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea texto;
    private JTextField txtMsg;
    private JButton btnSend;
    private JButton btnSair;
    private JLabel lblHistorico;
    private JLabel lblMsg;
    private JPanel pnlContent;
    private Socket socket;
    private OutputStream ou;
    private Writer ouw;
    private BufferedWriter bfw;
    private JTextField txtIP;
    private JTextField txtPorta;
    private JTextField txtNome;

    public Cliente() throws IOException {
        JLabel lblMessage = new JLabel("Verificar!");
        txtIP = new JTextField("127.0.0.1");
        txtPorta = new JTextField("12345");
        txtNome = new JTextField("Cliente");
        //
        Object[] texts = {lblMessage, txtIP, txtPorta, txtNome};
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, texts);
        pnlContent = new JPanel();
        texto = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        texto.setEditable(false);
        texto.setBackground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
        txtMsg = new JTextField(20);
        // 
        lblHistorico = new JLabel("Histórico");
        lblMsg = new JLabel("Mensagem");
        btnSend = new JButton("Enviar");
        btnSend.setToolTipText("Enviar Mensagem");
        btnSair = new JButton("Sair");
        btnSair.setToolTipText("Sair do Chat");
        //
        btnSend.addActionListener(this);
        btnSair.addKeyListener(this);
        btnSend.addKeyListener(this);
        txtMsg.addKeyListener(this);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(texto);
        texto.setLineWrap(true);
        //
        pnlContent.add(lblHistorico);
        pnlContent.add(scroll);
        pnlContent.add(lblMsg);
        pnlContent.add(txtMsg);
        pnlContent.add(btnSair);
        pnlContent.add(btnSend);
        //
        pnlContent.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        texto.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE));
        txtMsg.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE));
        //
        setTitle(txtNome.getText());
        setContentPane(pnlContent);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        // Tamanho da janela
        setSize(250, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    /*
    * Método usado para conectar no server socket, retorna IO Exception caso dê algum erro.
    * @throws IOException
    */
    public void conectar() throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket(txtIP.getText(), Integer.parseInt(txtPorta.getText()));
        ou = socket.getOutputStream();
        ouw = new OutputStreamWriter(ou);
        bfw = new BufferedWriter(ouw);
        bfw.write(txtNome.getText() + "\r\n");
        bfw.flush();
    }
    
    /*
    * Método usado para enviar mensagem para o server socket
    * @param msg do tipo String
    * @throws IOException retorna IO Exception caso dê algum erro.
    */
    public void enviarMensagem(String msg) throws IOException {
        if(msg.equals("Sair")) {
            bfw.write("Desconectado \r\n");
            texto.append("Desconectado \r\n");
        } else {
            bfw.write(msg + "\r\n");
            texto.append(txtNome.getText() + " diz -> " + txtMsg.getText() + "\r\n");
        }
        bfw.flush();
        txtMsg.setText("");
    }
    
    /*
    * Método usado para receber mensagem do servidor
    * @throws IOException retorna IO Exception caso dê algum erro.
    */
    public void escutar() throws IOException {
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(inr);
        String msg = "";
        
        while(!"Sair".equalsIgnoreCase(msg)) {
            if(bfr.ready()) {
                msg = bfr.readLine();
            }
            if(msg.equals("Sair")) {
                texto.append("Servidor caiu! \r\n");
            }
            else {
                texto.append(msg + "\r\n");
            }
        }
    }
    
    /*
    * Método usado quando o usuário clica em sair
    * @throws IOException retorna IO Exception caso dê algum erro.
    */
    public void sair() throws IOException {
        enviarMensagem("Sair");
        bfw.close();
        ouw.close();
        ou.close();
        socket.close();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals(btnSend.getActionCommand())){
                enviarMensagem(txtMsg.getText());
            }
            else {
                if(e.getActionCommand().equals(btnSair.getActionCommand())) {
                    sair();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // Todo Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            try {
                enviarMensagem(txtMsg.getText());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // Todo Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // Todo Auto-generated method stub
    }
    
    @Override
    public void KeyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // Todo Auto-generated method stub
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Cliente app = new Cliente();
        app.conectar();
        app.escutar();
    }

}
```

I'm using the NetBains IDE.

Comment: Don't use a `KeyListener` to trap a the [Enter] key, use a `ActionListener` instead

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener on your buttons and text fields. You should be using an `ActionListener`. The `ActionListener` will handle the button click on the button and the `Enter` key on the text field. If you want to activate the button when the Enter key is pressed check out [Enter Key and Button](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/enter-key-and-button/) for some options.

Comment: Also, make sure that your code obeys Swing threading rules (yours does not)

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to keep an eye on this now.